# java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,

Tags: android

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'  ->RedLine
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
implementation files('libs/achartengine-0.7.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
implementation files('libs/Beep_SHC.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/core-3.2.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.8.jar')
implementation files('libs/Java-WebSocket-1.3.8.jar')
implementation files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/libgpio.jar')
implementation files('libs/libpwm.jar')
implementation files('libs/libuart.jar')
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
implementation files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-3.jar')
implementation files('libs/opencsv-3.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/pl2303multilib.jar')
implementation files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
implementation files('libs/zip4j-1.3.2.jar')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'  ->RedLine
}
```

AndroidMenifest but more that activity , receiver...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="packageName"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1.47.b">    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
```

Manifest in android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS and WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE etc 
RedLine
build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
//        complie 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Log is a lot so register only a part

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
```

I don't know why error to occur. please tell me more
I'm sorry, I didn't know that for the first time stackoverflow.
thanks.

Comment: Please provide an explanation and code to your problem and not just the error code.

Comment: declare your android external libraries first like this 
   `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`

Comment: Can you please use code-formattinf for the error.

Answer (score 0):

this error is coming because your targetSdkVersion is 26 or you are using 28 either change the targetSdkVersion or dependencies version

Comment: i change targetSdkVersion 28 but error occur //  compileSdkVersion 28// targetSdkVersion 28 change this

Comment: try to decrease the value of buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" also may be it will work

Comment: may i gradle-wrapper.properties also change?? // distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip and        what's change ? buildTollsVersion "28.0.3"???

Comment: still getting error?..then set distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip instead of 5.4.1 afer doing these follow the process  build->clean project,then Rebuild project

Comment: rachna i one more question. when migrate android studio . 
Should I comment out the adt part of the file in Eclipse(.classpath file , .project file) when migrating?

Comment: And i fix it 5.4.1 -> 5.1.1 and still getting error : ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.1 migration Makes me tired

Comment: firstly define why did you added all dependencies so that i can help you

Comment: I'm doing it all over again , Can you help me ?

Comment: actually i don't have idea with eclipse that's why not able to find the issue